# Is there a pre-existing function to pass a tuple as args?

Tags: f#

I want to apply a regular function that takes two arguments to a tuple. I defined a helper function like so:

```
let apply f (a, b) =
    f a b
```

However I feel like this must be a fairly common use case and wondered if it was a function in the standard library (I'm not sure what terms to search for)

Comment: Tuple.Create method is a factory for tuples and it has a number of overloads with various number of argument.  What are you looking for specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [double forward pipe (`||>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340237.aspx) does this.

Comment: Thanks, I read up on the operator and ended up replacing my function with the identical operator in function form `(<||)` (although I'm not sure it helps my code readability!)

Comment: When `<||` isn't good enough, try `<|||`!  That'll be sure to improve your readability!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370477.aspx