# Is there an existing function to apply a function to each member of a tuple?

Tags: f#

I want to apply a function to both members of a homogenous tuple, resulting in another tuple. Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840206) I defined an operator that seemed to make sense to me:

```
let (||>>) (a,b) f = f a, f b
```

However, again I feel like this might be a common use case but couldn't find it in the standard library. Does it exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any standard library function that does this.

My personal preference would be to avoid too many custom operators (they make code shorter, but they make it harder to read for people who have not seen the definition before). Applying function to both elements of a tuple is logically close to the *map* operation on lists (which applies a function to all elements of a list), so I would probably define `Tuple2.map`:

```
module Tuple2 = 
  let map f (a, b) = (f a, f b)
```

Then you can use the function quite nicely with pipelining:

```
let nums = (1, 2)
nums |> Tuple2.map (fun x -> x + 1)
```

Comment: I like your reasoning, I'll take your recommendation. Can I ask why you define a new module `Tuple2` rather than extend the existing `Tuple`?

Comment: Ah... the 2 refers to the size of the tuple?

Comment: @AlexG Yes :-) the name `Tuple2` was referring to the size of the tuple. But if you just need two-element tuples, then `Tuple.map` or `Pair.map` would be nicer.

Comment: I would think that the proper `map` definition for pairs is `let map f g (a,b) = (f a, g b)`. Probably useless though.